# What is the best online tool for programming a iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

I think they're call iPhone simulators. Where can I find one?

Answer (score 2):

Take two steps back and start read up on iOS Development. Just go to www.google.com . There is an IDE called Xcode that you use for developing on iOS. There isn't an online tool. An iPhone Simulator is only a simulator that ships with Xcode on which you can test your app.

Comment: You get Xcode in the Mac App Store for free, if you are using Mountain Lion.

Comment: Strictly speaking, iOS development is not tied to Xcode. Xcode is just an IDE as you mentioned too. The essential parts are the toolchain (compiler, linker, debugger...) and the development sysroot with all the headers and libraries.